# Как сделать внутренний отступ маркера от списка?

Tags: html, css

Есть список, там нужно увеличить расстояние от маркера до пункта. Не могу понять, как это сделать.
По дефолту `list-style-position: outside` и я всегда увеличивал расстояние через `padding`. Но здесь принципиально важно сделать `list-style-position: inside`. `padding` тогда не работает. Не могу понять, как сделать это

Упрощённый кусок кода:

```css
li {
  background-color: pink;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Уберите стандартный маркер. А пунктам сделайте псевдоэлементы. Толкаете пункты пэддингом сколько нужно, а маркеры-псевдоэлементы ставите через left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как бы это реализовал я:

```css
li {
  background-color: pink;
  list-style-position: inside;

  list-style: none;
  position: relative;

  --marker-size: 5px;
  --gap-right: 5px;
  --gap-left: 5px;

  padding-left: calc(var(--marker-size) * 2 + var(--gap-right) + var(--gap-left));
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  width: var(--marker-size);
  height: var(--marker-size);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - calc(var(--marker-size) / 2));
  left: calc(var(--marker-size) / 2 + var(--gap-left));
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Пункт 1</li>
</ul>
```

### Как поменять размер маркера?

За это отвечает пропорция `--marker-size`, там вы указываете размер маркера, а уже сами стили правильно располагают его.

### Как мне регулировать расстояние между маркером и пунктом?

Чтобы регулировать расстояние между маркером и пунктом нужно изменять пропорцию `--gap-right`, она отвечает за расстояние которое добавляется с правой стороны.

Чтобы отрегулировать расстояние слева, меняйте пропорцию `--gap-left`, она отвечает за расстояние которое добавляется с левой стороны.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Изначально этот способ не рассматривал, но, кажется, альтернативы нет

Comment: @DarkSpace не за что! Не уверен, что есть какие-то другие способы не используя псевдо элементы (по типу `::before`, `::after` и `::marker`), мой вариант решения один из самых удобных, его легко настраивать как нужно.

Comment: А если в `li` будет больше одной строки, маркер не будет ли по центру всего `li`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson разве? Я попробовал в `<li>` поставить два параграфа, маркер всё равно по центру (вертикально), всё как надо. Можете отправить пример в [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) где можно воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: Разве маркер должен быть посередине `li` даже при двух строках? По моему только напротив первой строки.

Comment: @OliverPatterson ну значит это особенность такая будет ‍♂️. К слову, если убрать `list-style: none;` и стили на `li::before`, то обычный маркер вообще над текстом "Пункт 1", так что не всё так плохо у меня :)